# Is it possible use Next.js with custom server and static/automatic optimization?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Can i use a custom server with static optimization provided by Next.js?

I know that documentation has an info explaining that is not possible, but is there a workaround to do this?

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like https://medium.com/@igordata/how-to-cache-all-pages-in-next-js-at-server-side-1850aace87dc - This uses a npm module on top of nextjs generated pages.

I would be interested on your usecase, if SSG is important, why use a custom server?

Comment: The project already using the cache control. This is a legacy project that i need update to static optimization and i search an approach to remove the custom server with a minimum impact. Thank you!